# How to set status after email reading from Google Api

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api

Usually in normal mail the unread status will be changed as read
after we visit that mail like the same way how to find the status
as read while reading email content in google api code in c#

Comment: This should not be a duplicate.  The question is about MARKING a mail read not actual reading it.  This is two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Messages.modify](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify) method allows you to make changes to the message. You need to modify the message and remove the UNREAD label.  The message will then appear to be read

```
public static Message ModifyMessage(GmailService service, String userId,
      String messageId, List<String> labelsToAdd, List<String> labelsToRemove)
  {
      ModifyMessageRequest mods = new ModifyMessageRequest();
      mods.RemoveLabelIds = "UNREAD";

      try
      {
          return service.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, userId, messageId).Execute();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
      }

      return null;
  }
```

**Not on access**

This method requires one of the following scopes of access

- https://mail.google.com/
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

Comment: 0
down vote
favorite
I am following this code to mark unread email as read in my gmail using Google API C# Code. This is the code return service.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, userId, messageId).Execute(); but i am getting the following error

Error Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Insufficient Permission [403] Errors [Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]]

How to resolve this issue for Gmail reading using Google Api C#

Comment: Make sure you have your scopes set properly  Check the edit on which scopes you should be using.

Comment: I seen your update . But where i include this url? Not on access

This method requires one of the following scopes of access

https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify

Comment: Try to reauthorize the user then try again.  Insufficient Permission means you dont have permission.  sounds like you are using a readonly or metadata permission.   If that doesnt work please edit your question and add your code so i can test it.